# how to crop multiple images in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, automation, crop

I have a great amount of figures with the same properties and I would like to crop them all in the same way.

Is there a faster way to do it in Inkscape instead of doing it one by one?

Comment: Maybe Image-magick is more appropriate for that task. But I don't know all abilities of inkscape.

Comment: If your figures are all SVG, then you may script the changes using an [XML editor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91791/grep-and-sed-equivalent-for-xml-command-line-processing).

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information? (1) Are all the figures in separate SVG files or all in a single file? (2) Are you intending to to end up with a PNG file (meaning the cropping could be done during export) or do you want to crop and end up with another SVG file? (3) What is the specific rule by which you are cropping? For example, to a specific size, fit-canvas-to-image, or something else. (4) Will any images need to be scaled up or down during cropping?

Answer (score 2):

At least in Inkscape 0.91 r (May 20 2016), I could directly set one clip on multiple objects. Setting the clip worked for vector and raster image objects at the same time.

1. Place the objects you want to clip on top of each other.
2. Place the mask you want to use for clipping on the very top.
3. Select everything and click `Object > Clip > Set`. The topmost object should be used as a clip for each object below.

The image below shows the scene before (top left) and after (bottom left) clipping. The black object was used for clipping. For clarity, the right-hand side shows the objects in the background.

[image: Same clip on multiple objects]